# Update list from another list if not found then insert

Tags: c#, linq, list

In my application I have to check if `MyListDeepCopy` is `empty`, if it is i will copy original list:

```
MyListDeepCopy = new List<Storage>(Storage.MyStorage);
```

Now that `MyListDeepCopy` is populated I want to check each time original `list` changes. If `item` is added to original `list` i will have to `insert` new item to `MyListDeepCopy` else `update` it.

Could someone show me an example how its done? (possible with LINQ)

EDIT: I have solved it by doing this: (insert)

```
if (MyListDeepCopy.Count() == 0)
    {
        MyListDeepCopy  = new List<Storage>(Storage.MyStorage);
    }
    else 
    {
        var ItemOnDeepList = Storage.MyStorage.Where(x => !MyListDeepCopy.Any(y => x.ItemID == y.ItemID));
        if(ItemOnDeepList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ItemOnDeepList) 
            {
                MyListDeepCopy.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You pretty much described what to do. Just follow your own steps one by one, you will be there.

Comment: what problem(s) do you face?

Comment: You've only shown us one list, which makes it harder to understand what's going on. Also, you should show us what you've tried already, and what happened. (I suggest you look at the various LINQ operations available to you and think about which of those might be relevant...)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example. In this I am Updating the List if item found else adding an item.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var originalList = CreateOriginalList();// Original List
        List<Item> MyListDeepCopy = new List<Item>();// Empty List

        // Copy Original List to MyListDeepCopy if later is empty.
        if (MyListDeepCopy.Count() == 0)
            MyListDeepCopy = (List<Item>)originalList;

        {
            /* DELETE IF FOUND */
            int dItemId = 11;

            // Update originalList
            originalList.RemoveAll(d => d.ItemId == dItemId);
            // Update same in MyListDeepCopy
            MyListDeepCopy.RemoveAll(d => d.ItemId == dItemId);
        }


        {
            /* ADD IF NOT EXIST ELSE UPDATE */
            int aItemId = 17;
            double aItemPrice = 1200;

            // ADD to originalList
            originalList.Add(new Item { ItemId = aItemId, ItemPrice = aItemPrice });

            // Update 
            if (MyListDeepCopy.Exists(a => a.ItemId == aItemId))
                (MyListDeepCopy.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ItemId == aItemId)).ItemPrice = aItemPrice;
            else
                MyListDeepCopy.Add(new Item { ItemId = aItemId, ItemPrice = aItemPrice });
        }          
    }

    private static List<Item> CreateOriginalList()
    {
        return new List<Item> 
        {
            new Item{ ItemId = 11, ItemPrice = 100},
            new Item{ ItemId = 12, ItemPrice = 1000},
            new Item{ ItemId = 13, ItemPrice = 1050},
            new Item{ ItemId = 14, ItemPrice = 600},
            new Item{ ItemId = 15, ItemPrice = 900}
        };            
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemId{get; set;}
    public double ItemPrice { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}  :  {1}", ItemId, ItemPrice);
    }
}
```